# CardView layout has huge spacing inbetween them when i scroll down

Tags: android, xml, listview, search, android-linearlayout

I'm making sort of an inventory search app. I have a problem whereby I try to scroll up and down a huge space between the card view that appears out of nowhere. When I make a search the layout resets to normal but the moment I make a scroll the problem arises. Below is my list_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="17dp"
        android:background="#EFEFEF"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_column="0"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold">

                        </TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:text="Over 700 items in store!"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold">

                        </TextView>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#FF0000">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="ON SALE !"
                                android:textColor="#fff"
                                android:textStyle="bold">

                            </TextView>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/checkout_button"
                            android:onClick="groceries_click"
                            android:text="shop now!"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textSize="12dp">
                        </Button>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[The image of the view get before I scroll down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UopFR.png)  ||  [This is the behaviour I get after a scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmSED.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen because you make `match_parent` on your tag `<LinearLayout/>`

Change into `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" //Change into wrap_content
    android:padding="6dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```